# message: "CSRF token mismatch." Error 419

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hello I am trying to post data via ajax but i face this error and i am sure that i called CSRF_TOKEN in header section

Header Section :
**meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"**

Route Section :

**Route::post('cart/data/store/{id}', [CartController::class, 'AddToCart']);**

Ajax Code :

```
function addToCart() {
  
  var product_name = $('#pname').text();
  var id =    $('#product_id').val();
  var color = $('#color option:selected').text();
  var size =  $('#size option:selected').text();
  var quantity = $('#qty').val();

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"JSON",
    data:{
      color:color, 
      size:size, 
      quantity:quantity, 
      product_name:product_name,
    },
    url: "cart/data/store/"+id,
    success:function(data) {
      $('#closeModal').click();
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
}
```

Controller :

class CartController extends Controller
{
public function AddToCart(Request $request, $id) {

```
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    if ($product->discount_price == NULL) {
        
        Cart::add([
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $request->product_name,
            'qty' => $request->quantity,
            'price' => $product->selling_price,
            'weight' => 1,
            'options' => [
                'image' => $product->product_thumbnail,
                'size' => $request->size,
                'color' => $request->color,
            ],
        ]);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Item Added To Your Cart']);
        
    } else {
        Cart::add([
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $request->product_name,
            'qty' => $request->quantity,
            'price' => $product->discount_price,
            'weight' => 1,
            'options' => [
                'size' => $request->size,
                'color' => $request->color,
                'image' => $product->product_thumbnail
            ],
        ]);
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Item Added To Your Cart']);
    }
    
}
```

}

Token Section :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers:{
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
  }
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, paste the code in your question so we can copy paste to an answer. Did you even search SO? There are multiple questions on CSRF mismatch....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, first, don't post images but texts, easier to read for us. Then, be sure to read the doc carefully: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token, you must set the token in your ajax calls. They have an example.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answers
okay i will edit it 

but i have searched many times on differents sites but i did everything right and inserted the CSRF_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

add @csrf in beginning of your form.

```
<form id="my_form" >
   @csrf
   <input type="text" name="name"id="name" >
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: not really this is ajax code not a html form

Comment: you can do like this  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
        });
    });